# How to remove javascript code injection from a URL on HubSpot?

Tags: javascript, warnings, hubspot

One of our clients received a social engineering warning from google. There is nothing hosted on the client's site and all I can assume is that the code is embedded in the URL. How can I stop this and make sure that the URL is not being taken advantage of?

Code below -

```
http://blog.essentialtech.com[.]au/events/public/v1/track/c/*W42X1Kh4VlKV7W4NDyrQ4Jwqwc0/*W34SKKS4FTw8nW7PlP8S8lBlFP0/5/f18dQhb0SfHC9dsQ84N7cW9rzHyjJqVS9MQR2B872gW3hHhb35zh-NRVnQ9Qq8Z_8m8W328bd38Xl1YFW2Mk5st5mZ50NMH5sdmJ4m23N8_dF8cJVPWRW4c2Tyb6d_m0TVHG2xy2R1bM2W2N6lzq4cj1_jW2pzD7d2MTPSyVKng6q1Wg4bjW58jf-C34RCjxW2p2f452LHP4rW5x5KNk7-XB_5N4Qzp5DMBCsfW7pKMHF2K4XMjW8tzC3F8q-1tCN1KKm4vRFkK4W5G18Kh3y9KYQN3dgtM7YrDrqW5hfJ425v5Cb1W8x-WCY3tg8kZN6p6WGsDLwCnW5BLL855GJB9nW5lW2Zn30_g8xW5kXBFn6n161-W38SQwr2Yy7gbW8Knjr38f7c2WW5rTvwF42SsX8W5nLxq_8r0-2RW30v4M38wyznpN3Gyjm6BNxmYW3gfMK48j556ZN8q1-LpjGXPKN64V3lHJRhw9VcZLWR86l4pCW8yq-Kr3rJTdsN5d_Q0Zj8tbNW480YZF3psJYWW8l-5SS6S8BxvW2RLxLy7X8G2fW5SdKBQ8s1s46W32wFFH1NsfDKSqhY367YLr102?_ud=617a5272-4c86-4d80-987a-d62228fd4f5e
```

Comment: I received a similar warning for a HubSpot site. I have yet to solve the issue, but have reached out to HubSpot for support. Have you been able to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This could be referring to a situation where in your code you're directly outputting the value of a query parameter or URL part in your page itself.

HubSpot has some automatic protections to prevent that kind of code injection, but there's still some best practices you should follow regardless of what CMS platform you're using.

Never trust query parameters as having only valid data. Never directly output it on the page. You can use HubL filters such as `|escape` and `|striptags` to remove potentially harmful code in the event you do need to display the value in the page.

An example of a time you might do that might be for a search results page, where you show "Search results for :"